# STUFF in MS SQL query that I need to query within it using AND

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I hope this question won't be too hard to understand but here goes.

I have a query that uses the **STUFF()** operator that is set **AS Roles**. The output for **Roles** is:

```
 Main Administrator, Per Admin, Coordinator
```

Now I wish to use this **Roles** within my querys' **AND** properties like so:

```
 Select 
    *, STUFF(blah blah...) AS Roles 
 FROM
    table AS T1 
 INNER JOIN table2 AS T2
    ON T1.user = T2.user 
 Where 
    .... 
 AND 
    Roles = 'Per Admin'
```

However, there are 2 things wrong.

1) I am not able to use the "Roles" within the **AND** operator stating that the error is 'Invalid column name 'Roles'.

2) Once I get #1 above working, I need to be able to find **Per Admin** within those listed Roles. I am thinking it might involve some type of **string_split** or something similar?

Help would be great from a SQL Guru :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add EXISTS to your query and duplicate the STUFF query or something similar and add your filter in the EXISTS.

```
Select 
    *, STUFF(blah blah...) AS Roles 
 FROM
    table AS T1 
 INNER JOIN table2 AS T2
    ON T1.user = T2.user 
 Where 
    .... 
 AND 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM blahblah WHERE RoleName = 'Per Admin')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subquery or cte:

```
with cte as (<your query here>)
select cte.*
from cte
where . . . and
      cte.roles = 'Per admin';
```

If you want to find that role among other roles, then something like this:

```
where ',' + cte.roles + ',' like '%,' + 'Per admin' + ',%'
```

Comment: Not sure that I follow Gordon. Would you mind using my example in my OP and wrap your code around that so I can better understand it?

Comment: @StealthRT . . . Your code (well, without the condition on `roles` goes where `<your query here>` is.

Comment: Tells me **'The column 'userID' was specified multiple times for 'cte'.**

Comment: Instead of `SELECT *` in your query, specify which columns you'd like. You `userID` exists in `table` and `table2`. You can only specify one to return.

Comment: **up vote** for the help on the names being the same :o)

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below query.

```
   ;With cte_1
    AS
   (Select    T1.User, ..other columns.., STUFF(blah blah...) AS Roles 
     FROM    table AS T1 
     INNER JOIN table2 AS T2
         ON T1.user = T2.user )
     Select *
     From cte_1
     Where Roles  like '%Per Admin%'
```

Comment: Tells me **'The column 'userID' was specified multiple times for 'cte'.**

Comment: Use specific column names inside the cte query instead of *.since table and table1 contains the same column 'user' , it is throwing this error.

Comment: **up vote** for the help on the names being the same :o)